# How to convert struct function to a named_struct expression correctly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

env: spark2.4.3

## example.json

```
{
    "array0": [
        {
            "a": "1",
            "b": "2"
        },
        {
            "a": "3",
            "b": "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to change every field name of struct in `array0` to such .json with spark-sql API:

```
{
        "array0": [
            {
                "A": "1",
                "B": "2"
            },
            {
                "A": "3",
                "B": "4"
            }
        ]
    }
```

load:

```
val source = spark.read.format("json").option("multiLine", "true").load("/home/user/Desktop/example.json")
```

And I have to generate my structure with an API because of some specs.(I used `struct` here, and `named_struct` is not an API so I can't use it)

```
val my_struct = struct(col("x.a").as("A"), col("x.b").as("B"))
```

Cos in spark2.4.3 transform API hasn't been supported yet so I generate it with the `expr()` function

```
val my_transform = expr("transform("+"array0,"+"x->"+my_struct.expr.sql+")")
```

And it throws:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input 'AS' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 58)
```

It seems that `expr()` doesn't support `my_struct.expr.sql`. I'm confused.

So how can I give a correct struct sql string to `expr()`?

Or some other solutions anyone can give me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't nees `transform` just to rename your fields, you can use Schema DSL. The shortest way to rename your struct would be:

```
val newDF = df.select(col("array0").cast("array<struct<A:string,B:string>>"))

newDF.printSchema()
```

which gives:

```
root
 |-- array0: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
```

Instead of a String, you can also pass the the new schema as a `DataType`

Comment: I have to handle it with API mod (with transform and struct api

Answer (score 0):

Alternative -
If you want to go with `transform`

### Load the data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |{
        |    "array0": [
        |        {
        |            "a": "1",
        |            "b": "2"
        |        },
        |        {
        |            "a": "3",
        |            "b": "4"
        |        }
        |    ]
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------------+
      * |array0          |
      * +----------------+
      * |[[1, 2], [3, 4]]|
      * +----------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- array0: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

```scala
    val processedDF = df.withColumn("array0", expr("TRANSFORM(array0, " +
      "x -> named_struct('A', x.a, 'B', x.b))"))
    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----------------+
      * |array0          |
      * +----------------+
      * |[[1, 2], [3, 4]]|
      * +----------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- array0: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
      * |    |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: sorry, I have to do with API mode, so named_struct() doesn’t meet my demand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this directly

```
val my_transform = expr("""transform(array0,x->struct(x.a.as("A"), x.b.as("B")))""")
```